# Autobalance the shards in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

We have 4 ElasticSearch nodes in version 5.6.9, that for some previous rules, they have an unbalanced number of shards in each node.

We have found that we can move one shard at a time to another node, but that is incredibly slow.

Apart from creating a script that uses the ElasticSearch API to balance the shards, is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the issue, the system was not autorebalancing the cluster's indices, because we had the `cluster.routing.rebalance.enable = none`

We found the information [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shards-allocation.html).

The problem we had with the cluster/reroute, was the according to the documentation the system will try to balance itself again. Either way, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so using **Cluster Reroute** it allows for manual changes to the allocation of individual shards in the cluster. check out the docs [Cluster Reroute](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-reroute.html#cluster-reroute)

```
    POST /_cluster/reroute
{
    "commands" : [
        {
            "move" : {
                "index" : "test", "shard" : 0,
                "from_node" : "node1", "to_node" : "node2"
            }
        },
        {
          "allocate_replica" : {
                "index" : "test", "shard" : 1,
                "node" : "node3"
          }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The problem we had with the cluster reroute, is that according to the documentation, if we move a shard from node1 -> node2, the system will move another shard from node2 -> node1.

Probably with the cluster.routing.rebalance.enable = none, it wouldn't have moved, but that is not what we wanted.
Thanks for the help though.